# Extract a specific data from pdf files

Tags: pdf, pdfbox, text-extraction, data-extraction, extractor

Can someone give some solution, idea or just an indication about how I can extract some specific data from a pdf file, I used pdfbox with PDfTextStripper to extract all the text in the pdf file, it's working correctly I can extract all the text, word by word and line by line but I can't extract just some words (specific string: for example price, age) I want just extract some required data that I want to extract from the pdf file.

Comment: How can those specific strings you search be recognized? Probably some specific format? Or some preceding label? Or some specific position on the page? A unique colour? A different font?...

Answer (score 1):

You could use `pdfgrep` It works like `grep`, but instead of text files it can dig trough and find things that match given regex in pdf.
Hope this helps